Laravel: cannot catch exception from command listener
i am working on a task to log the command in the log file, to do this, i modified EventServiceProvidere.php file in app.Providers route:

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public $finished_time;
    public $starting_time;

    public $memory_usuage_start;
    public $memory_usuage_end;
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
       
        'Illuminate\Http\Client\Events\ResponseReceived' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogResponseReceived',
        ],

        'Illuminate\Http\Client\Events\ConnectionFailed' => [
            LogResponseReceived::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $subscribe = [
        AutoChargeSettingListener::class,
    ];

     public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen(CommandStarting::class, function (CommandStarting $event) {
            $this->memory_usuage_start = memory_get_peak_usage();
        });

        Event::listen(CommandFinished::class, function (CommandFinished $event) {
            $this->finished_time = microtime(true);
            $exit_code = $event->exitCode;
            try{
              // here you can store, display or log time for future use.
            Log::info("Command exit: ".$exit_code);

            }catch(Exception $e){
                Log::info(222);
            }
        });
    }
}


when the command file has no exception, the log info is expected, but when the command file has exception, my test log info (222) cannot be listed in the log file, it seems that when the command file has exception, this file cannot catch the exception, can you please help me to figure it out? MANY THANKS!
I tried to make some tests

The try/catch is only for the logging, it doesn't have anything to do with the Command exception. All uncaught exceptions run through App\Exceptions\Handler.php, so try adding something there.
